# How do I set my price in woocommerce when it does not show up?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm your below average dropshipping guy and I'm struggling with something:

I cannot set my product price. Wordpress -> products -> Edit product;

Nowhere on this page, i can set a price. Under no tab there is a price option. Has someone encountered this, or can help with this?

I have watched many youtube video's and searched on google but could not find it where everyone else have found it (which was in General tab mostly).

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your product type to  "simple product" 
[image]